Does conducting puja and havans remotely on behalf of others provide the desired punyas?
Nowdays we have quite a few websites and apps in which one can book a puja,havan etc (e.g. Rudra Abhishekam) in mandirs without you participating in it. Such websites also provide services such as grihya shanti puja for your house remotely. I feel engaging such services won't help. But are there any legit sources that claim otherwsie.

There're 2 aspects here.... 1 Pujas/homas done as a propitiation with the intention of some specific objective 2. nishkaamya or without any personal objective..  in the latter case it's done to please the devata so there's accrual of punya. In the former case a sankalpa is essential for fructification of the intended objective and a sankalpa is ineffective if without the kAla & desha being mentioned. Somebody sitting in USA cannot recite a sankalpa for indian time and place. So this renders the sankalpa ineffective thereby negating any fruits of the homa.
